# What is the real "Consortium" as mentioned in Dan Brown's Inferno?

Tags: inspiration, dan-brown, inferno

On the "FACT" page of the book *Inferno* by Dan Brown:

> "The Consortium" is a private organization with offices in seven countries. Its name has been changed for considerations of security and privacy.

What is this organization, really?

Comment: See [Dan Browned](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DanBrowned)

Comment: Warning: TVTropes link.